I did epub with svg and it worked on google play books and calibre but not kindle, what might be an issue?
I had my document showing simplest svg. It was working elsewhere (calibre, google play books) but not Kindle.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
    <title>Unknown</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body class="calibre">
       <p>rem</p>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:3rem;height:3rem;"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"/>
       </svg>
</body>
</html>

I had opf file correctly set with properties="svg"
<item id="html" href="tst.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" properties="svg"/>


I find out that svg actually doens't support rem units. Though it works elsewere it doesn't work for Kindle. Correct is basically to use any other unit than rem. Even em is possible. But I used px Now it works also in Kindle.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
    <title>Unknown</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body class="calibre">
       <p>px</p>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:50px;height:50px;"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"/>
       </svg>
</body>
</html>

